# Extract values from array in order to replace the default numerical key

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have some data in the database, in this format:

```
Description~Level||Description~Level||
```

I want to transform this into an array where description is the Key & Level the value of the array.

```
$perso1 = explode('||', $myLevels['perso']);
$perso = array_slice($perso1, 0 , -1);
```

so far ive done this and it return that :

```
Array ( [0] => ffghtr~54644
        [1] => ffghtr~54644
        [2] => ffghtr~54644
        [3] => ffghtr~54644
        [4] => ffghtr~54644
        [5] => ffghtr~54644 )
```

Now I cannot find a way to replace the array keys (0,1,2,etc) by my description.

Any idea ?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tmp = explode('||', $myLevels['perso']);
foreach ($tmp as $str) {
    // this check is to remove empty elements from the list .. 
    // because your list ends with "||" there is a last empty element
    if(strpos($str, "~") === false) continue;
    // split by "~" into $key and $value
    list($key, $value) = explode("~", $str, 2);
    $result[$key] = $value;
}
print_r($result);
```

Please note that in the posted example you always have the same key: "ffghtr".

Because array keys are unique, you will end up replacing the content of this key with every iteration, having only the last element as the result.

Comment: Awesome! Yes sorry I should have put different values in my example. The keys will be unique indeed. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = Array ( [0] => ffghtr~54644
    [1] => ffghtr~54644
    [2] => ffghtr~54644
    [3] => ffghtr~54644
    [4] => ffghtr~54644
    [5] => ffghtr~54644 ) 

$new_array = new Array();
foreach($array as $a)
     $new_array[(split('~',$a))[0]] = (split('~',$a))[1]
```

So new_array should be in the form you want. Actually i did not test the code but you got the idea. Please note the array you posted has always the same key: ffghtr.

So yuo'll end up with a new_array of only one element...